# Matriz 5x5 com Portugol - Aprendendo a programar

Tags: portugol, visualg

Sou estudante e estou começando a aprender sobre programação, tenho um exercício que por mim mesmo não consegui resolve-lo e gostaria de saber se alguém aqui poderia me ajudar, com a solução e/ou com uma explicação para que eu possa compreender isso e tentar resolver outros semelhantes a este por mim mesmo.

Preciso de um **algoritmo em Portugol**, que tenha uma matriz 5x5 , onde cada posição representa uma cidade: A,B,C,D,E cada uma com uma distância pré-definida 
devo colocar por quais cidades passei (percorrer a matriz) depois dizer a distância percorrida , e/ou a distância de uma cidade até a outra.

Referência:

> https://vinyanalista.github.io/portugol/

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt! Uma comunidade voltada para auxiliar na resolução de problemas pontuais relativos ao desenvolvimento de software e afins. Creio que aqui não seja o melhor lugar para pedir que alguém faça o seu trabalho de faculdade. ;)

Comment: O único problema é que **parece** (não digo que é) que você não demonstrou esforço de pesquisa, isso deixa o pessoal aqui meio chateado em responder esse tipo de pergunta, mas é totalmente válida sua pergunta, é clara, é bem definida em termos de começo meio e fim resumindo é uma dúvida sobre programação legítima, não sei porque estão votando para fecha-la, o exemplo minimo, completo e verificável que estão usando para justificar o fechamento esta sendo usado de forma errada, o minimo é o pseudo código, completo é a explicação do problema e verificável seria a parte que alguém poderia ajuda-lo

Comment: algumas pessoas não conseguem ver que o exemplo minimo, completo e verificável nem sempre esta escrito em forma de código de fonte, e isso é um erro da comunidade que precisa ser ajustado o quanto antes, para que possamos ampliar o numero de pessoas que utilizam o SOPT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beleza vamos lá

```
algoritmo
declare mat[5,5], resultado[5,5], i, j, distancia numerico
para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
inicio
    para j <- 1 ate 5 faca
    inicio
        leia mat[i,j]
    fim
fim
distancia <- mat[1,1]
para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
inicio
    para j <- 1 ate 5 faca
    inicio
        se mat[i,j] > distancia entao
            distancia <- mat[i,j]
    fim
fim
para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
inicio
    para j <- 1 ate 5 faca
    inicio
        resultado[i,j] <- distancia * mat[i,j]
    fim
fim
para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
inicio
    para j <- 1 ate 5 faca
    inicio
        escreva resultado[i,j]
    fim
fim
fim_algoritmo.

// Adaptado de:
// ASCENCIO, A. F. G.; CAMPOS, E. A. V. Fundamentos da programação de
// computadores. 2a. ed. São Paulo: Pearson Prentice Hall, 2007. p. 198.
```

E agora quando alguém perguntar alguma coisa desse código você vai saber responder ? Minha dica é veja onde tem dúvidas, poste uma dúvida ou um problema que seja verificável para que os colegas aqui possam dar soluções ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Sobre oque você comentou na minha pergunta.. Eu acho que essa comunidade seria meio que um fórum e pudesse me ajudar, não sou o Einstein, sou um novato em programação.. Fico muito chateado com isso, pareçe que aqui as pessoas dão voto negativo pra f**** com quem  tem a pergunta.. O jeito é apagar/esqueçer a conta e sair dessa comunidade, obrigado realmente pela ajuda!

Comment: Entra no meu perfil ai.. Só tem pergunta com voto negativo! Sou novo aqui, mas achei essa "comunidade" (porque isso pra min não é pra ser chamado de comunidade) meio hipócrita.. Não sabem lhe dar com pessoas, não sabem lhe dar com perguntas "idiotas", se é uma pergunta, mesmo que seja o máximo de idiota, é uma pergunta. Realmente não gostei dessa "comunidade", e prefiro muito mais forums que lá tem moderação e são pessoas comuns, sejam novatos até experientes.

Comment: Existe um lugar aqui chamado **meta** onde debatemos temas que norteiam tudo sobre o que acontece aqui, lá é onde supostamente se decide o que vale e o que não vale, já foi discutido se aqui é um bom lugar para quem quer começar a aprender a programar da uma passadinha lá e deixe seu recado para os demais será importante eles verem que muita coisa que eles dizem lá na prática não acontece aqui http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4818/stackoverflow-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-boa-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-quem-quer-come%C3%A7ar-a-programar

Comment: @STRILEXLIVE percebo a sua frustração, dei uma olhada nas suas perguntas e vi que alguns votos negativos não fazem sentido, mas não leve isso para o lado pessoal, os votos negativos é um sinal para o autor de que há algo de errado com a pergunta e que o conteúdo pode ser melhorado. Em relação a pergunta deste tópico, eu concordo com os votos negativos, você simplesmente pediu para alguém fazer o seu trabalho. Você diz que o SOpt não parece uma comunidade e você tem razão, ele por si só não é uma comunidade, para ser tal depende do comportamento das pessoas que aqui frequentam...

Comment: @STRILEXLIVE ... logo se torna uma comunidade quando os seus utilizadores se comportam de maneira adequada, ou seja, o seu comportamento esperando que outros resolvam o seu problema sem qualquer esforço da sua parte (pelo menos é a ideia que tenho ao ler a sua pergunta) não colabora para que o SOpt seja uma comunidade, você falhou na sua parte. Tome isso como uma crítica construtiva, tudo é questão de acão-reação.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes realmente você esta certo sobre minha pergunta, mas eu só fiz ela porque um amigo meu estava com essa dúvida e eu resolvi ajudar, e como não sei nada sobre Portugol... Olha aew http://prntscr.com/ah00p8 http://prntscr.com/ah00xe